# WebService REST pedido POST erro

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, restful

Ao fazer o pedido de POST é me devolvido esta mensagem de erro:

```
 O servidor remoto devolveu um erro: (400) Pedido incorrecto.
```

O IService encontra - se defenido desta forma:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "insert/?id={id}&v={v}&dt={dt}&qt={qt}",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [OperationContract]
        bool Insert(int id,int v, string dt, int qt);
```

e o Pedido faço da seguinte forma:

```
string uploadUrl = @"http://url/ServicePedido.svc/insert/?id=" + id + "&v=" + vim + "&dt=" + daregisto + "&qt=" + quantidade;
                WebRequest addRequest = WebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
                addRequest.Method = "POST";
                addRequest.ContentLength = 0;
                WebResponse addResponse = addRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: qual é o teu "RegisteredRoute" ao inicio da applicao? Tambem, embora nao tenho certeza, acho que "/?" pode ser problematica...normalmente era `/insert?id=1`

Comment: Quer dizer, o template tambem (normalmente) era `insert?id={id}&v={v}&dt={dt}&qt={qt}`

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma pesquisada, e tem uma galera recomendando esse app pra debugar requisição

http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Esse tipo de erro é bem indefinido , mas a maioria dos casos é :

1) estrutura do rest enviado não bate com nenhum template que foi construído
2) se o servidor de rest tiver dentro de uma área que requer estar logado.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350241/httpwebrequest-type-get-returning-error-400